# how to apply filter function to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Byte]]

Tags: apache-spark

After using spark to load thrift files:

```
val rdd1 = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[LongWritable,BinaryWritable[Array[Byte]],
        MultiInputFormat[Array[Byte]]]("s3://spark-tst/test/input/").map(_._2.get()),
```

I got RDDs in the format `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Byte]]`.  Now I need to apply filter function to these RDDs, but got `"org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable"`. If introducing an intermediate rdd "`val s = rdd1.collect.toList`" then the filter function can apply to RDD s; but "collect" is not suitable for the case with large number of files.  Another problem is that alter the filter, data also needs to write back to s3 in its original thrift format.
Appreciate any helps / suggestions.